# Class-based views: where to check for permissions?

Tags: python, django

I am not very comfortable using class-based views but I am aware of their perks so I am forcing myself to start using them more often.

There's this view that receives a path param: `manage/:id` to manage a particular entity.

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
  template_name = '...'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['entity'] = get_object_or_404(Entity, pk=self.args[0])
    return context
```

An `Entity` includes a list of authorized users to perform special actions. This view, `MyView` is one of those special actions.

I tried making a decorator for the view but it required finding the `Entity` first so I wasn't sure how to work that out.

Now, I have a `check_permission(request, entity)` function that checks if the current user is one of these authorized ones.

My question is where should I call this function in the class-based views like `MyView` which will be any of these views considered "special actions"?

Should I call it just from `get_context_data()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

put it into [dispatch()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch). It could look like this:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
   template_name = '...'

   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       entity = get_object_or_404(Entity, pk=args[0])
       if not check_permission(request, entity):
           raise Http404
       return super(MyView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Where do I retrieve the `entity`? Do I need to `get_object_or_404` both in `dispatch` and `get_context_data`?

Comment: `entity` is an instance of `Entity`? Cant remember from top of my head but you'll have the data needed to getting it (the same way as you do in `get_context_data()`) either in *args` and `**kwargs` or `self.args` and `self.kwargs`

Comment: sure that's my concern, I need to get it twice? isn't it possible to just `get_object_or_404(Entity, pk=self.args[0])` just once?

Comment: @dabadaba request should be the first argument to the dispatch method, it's not attached to self at that point.

Comment: your answer did not include that, I am going to edit it.

Comment: Actually, `self.request` is [set before `dispatch()` is called](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2b281cc35ed9d997614ca3c416928d7fabfef1ad/django/views/generic/base.py#L62), so both ways are valid.

Answer (score 8):

You can check permissions in the `dispatch` as yedpodtrzitko has said. I think it's also a good idea to throw it inside of a mixin that you can put on your views.

Here's an example:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied


class ViewPermissionsMixin(object):
    """Base class for all custom permission mixins to inherit from"""
    def has_permissions(self):
        return True 

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.has_permissions():
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super(ViewPermissionsMixin, self).dispatch(
            request, *args, **kwargs)

class MyCustomPermissionMixin(ViewPermissionsMixin):

    def has_permissions(self):
        # here you will have access to both
        # self.get_object() and self.request.user
        return self.request.user in self.get_object().special_list_of_people
```

Now you can throw `MyCustomPermissionMixin` on your view:

```
class MyView(MyCustomPermissionMixin, TemplateView):
    # ...
```

In your case, since you're using a `TemplateView`, you should also make a `get_object()` method that returns the object that you want to deal with. Template views don't have this method by default.

Finally, just want to say that you will love Django's class based views once you learn some more about how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Django Braces](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces), it's a solid set of mixins which are designed around permissions.

How specifically you deal with permissions depends largely on implementation. I've done it in dispatch() before which is the way Braces does it but if it's specific to an object or queryset, I'll do it in the actual get_object or get_queryset methods as part of a DetailView.

For example if you had a creator associated with an Entity, you could override `get_object` to check the current logged in user is the Entity's creator.

```
class EntityView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Thing

    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        return Entity.objects.get_object_or_404(
            pk=kwargs['entity_id'], 
            creator=self.request.user
        )
```

Note: LoginRequiredMixin is a part of Braces. Very slick.